# About number of posts in selected category

Tags: posts, categories

I have lots of categories. And each category contains many images in posts.

I want to display '(current number of post)/(total number of posts in selected category)'

for example: 3/9
where 3 = current number of post
      9 = total number of posts in selected category

There are so many categories and I do not want to write code for each category. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: what is current no of posts ?

Comment: @wordpresser: There are 9 posts and out of which number 3 post is open.

Comment: from your question, what I get is you need not to write code for each category, you can fetch categories as an array and then use foreach loop to calculate the posts for it.

Comment: I tried $category = get_queried_object(); echo $category->count; but not worked.  I dont want to show only total number but also current post number.

Comment: An important question - are you trying to display this information on `archive` or `single` view?

Comment: @Michal Mau: single                                                          I want to show number of post in selected category. as in mentioned format.

Answer (score 0):

[WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) has the following 
properties you might find handy:

`$wp_query->current_post` - Index of the post currently being displayed.

`$wp_query->found_posts` - The total number of posts found matching the current query parameters